# Parse CACM collection in Java

Tags: java, parsing, string-parsing

i'm having a problem parsin the [CACM collection](http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/resources/test_collections/cacm/) in java.

The collection has this format:

```
.I number
.T 
title
.A
authors
multiple authors allowed
.W
body
multiple lines of body allowed
```

I'm trying to extract each of the fields with this *extract* method:

```
public static String extract(char campo, String text,Boolean allowEmpty)
{
    String[] lines = text.split("\\r?\\n");
    /*for(String line:lines)
        System.out.println(line);*/
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean start = false;
    boolean end = false;
    for(String l:lines)
    {
        System.out.println(l);
        //System.out.println(line.charAt(0));
        if((l.charAt(0) == '.') && (l.charAt(1) == campo))
        {
            System.out.println("Detectado campo "+l.charAt(1));
            start = true;
            builder.append(l.substring(2)).append("\n");
        }
        else
        {   
            if(l.charAt(0) == '.')
            {
                //System.out.println(campo);
                break;
            }
            else if(start)
                builder.append(l); 
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

But i do not know why, it does only extract the *.I* field, and i cant get it to work with any other field. I'm clueless in regard to where to correct the code, or if the approximation is logical.
Any clue in this?

Thank you in advance.